# Generating a SHA256 hash with Crypto++, using a string as input and output?

Tags: c++, hash, stdstring, sha256, crypto++

I need an example of how to use Crypto++ to generate a SHA256 hash from a std::string and output a std::string. I can't seem to figure it out. Everything I've tried gives me invalid output.

Here's the new code after interjay's answer:

```
string SHA256(string data)
{
    byte const* pbData = (byte*) data.data();
    unsigned int nDataLen = data.size();
    byte abDigest[CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE];

    CryptoPP::SHA256().CalculateDigest(abDigest, pbData, nDataLen);

    return string((char*)abDigest);
}
```

The output for SHA256("A"); is

[image]

How can I turn this into a readable format?

Thanks to interjay's answer I was able to generate the final hash.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This line will give the wrong results:

```
unsigned int nDataLen = sizeof(pbData);
```

It will always give you the size of a pointer. What you want instead is `data.size()`.

Also, you don't need this part:

```
if(!CryptoPP::SHA256().VerifyDigest(abDigest, pbData, nDataLen))
{
    return SHA256(data);
}
```

It should always verify correctly, since you just calculated the digest based on the same data. And if it didn't, you'd go into infinite recursion.

To get readable output, you can convert it to hex. Here's an example for MD5 from the [Crypto++ Wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Hash_Functions), it should work for you if you replace MD5 with SHA256:

```
CryptoPP::MD5 hash;
byte digest[ CryptoPP::MD5::DIGESTSIZE ];
std::string message = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

hash.CalculateDigest( digest, (byte*) message.c_str(), message.length() );

CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
std::string output;
encoder.Attach( new CryptoPP::StringSink( output ) );
encoder.Put( digest, sizeof(digest) );
encoder.MessageEnd();

std::cout << output << std::endl;
```

Comment: Okay I made those changes and while it now seems to be giving me the same output each time, the output is in all gibberish of random weird characters.  How can I change it to a readable format?

Comment: Applying your example gives a conversion error from `const char*` to `const byte*`. `(byte*) message.c_str()` is the right conversion.

Answer (score 25):

This outputs a base64 string using the `CryptoPP::Base64Encoder`:

```
#include "sha.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "base64.h"

std::string SHA256HashString(std::string aString){
    std::string digest;
    CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;

    CryptoPP::StringSource foo(aString, true,
    new CryptoPP::HashFilter(hash,
      new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder (
         new CryptoPP::StringSink(digest))));

    return digest;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, I was looking for a way to do this with pipelining!

Comment: CryptoPP also uses [SIMD x64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) instructions that speed it up.

Comment: Hi, I saw similar code elsewhere.  I wonder why an explicit delete isn't needed for the HashFilter, Base64Encoder and StringSink?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Hei: yeah, looks like a bunch of memory leaks. Or, is the author a fan of Java. :)

Comment: No, this does not leak memory. This is idiomatic CyptoPP code using https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining

Comment: Very good answer but more usual to output as hex digits rather than base64

Answer (score 5):

Your code will expect a null-terminated string from the buffer you supply to the string constructor! Which means the result will almost certainly be wrong.

To enforce the digest size and, use the following instead:

`return std::string((char*)abDigest, CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE);`

Also with respect to printing it the following correctly produces the test vector `BA7816BF8F01CFEA414140DE5DAE2223B00361A396177A9CB410FF61F20015AD` for the string `"abc"`

```
std::string string_to_hex(const std::string& input)
{
  static const char* const lut = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  size_t len = input.length();

  std::string output;
  output.reserve(2 * len);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    const unsigned char c = input[i];
    output.push_back(lut[c >> 4]);
    output.push_back(lut[c & 15]);
  }
  return output;
}

std::string SHA256(std::string data)
{
  CryptoPP::byte const* pbData = (CryptoPP::byte*)data.data();
  unsigned int nDataLen = data.length();
  CryptoPP::byte abDigest[CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE];

  CryptoPP::SHA256().CalculateDigest(abDigest, pbData, nDataLen);

  // return string((char*)abDigest);  -- BAD!!!
  return std::string((char*)abDigest, CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE);
}

void test_cryptopp() {
  std::cout << string_to_hex(SHA256("abc")) << std::endl;
}
```