# SHA256 Hash calculation in C++

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to convert following C# code into C++

```
        SHA256 hash = SHA256.Create();
        hash.TransformBlock(key, 0, key.Length, null, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            hash.TransformBlock(cipheredSHA256Hash, 0, 32, null, 0);
        }
        hash.TransformFinalBlock(cipheredSHA256Hash,0, 0);

        using (RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijndael.Key = hash.Hash;
            rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor();

            return decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cipheredOffSet60, 0, cipheredOffSet60.Length);
        }
```

is there any option for above code in C++

Comment: *"I am trying"* - perhaps you'd care to show your effort so far, and say where you're stuck?

Comment: The C# code uses the .NET Base Class Library. Do you want to write a .NET application using C++? You can do that using [managed C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) which is a language based on C++. However, I suspect that you want to implement an unmanaged application (no .NET). In that case you can use [Windows CryptoAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having a look at the free [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) library. It implements several cryptographic algorithms, including SHA256 and AES/Rijndael.

Check the following discussions for examples on how to create SHA256 hashes and decrypt AES:

[Create a SHA256 hash with Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930056/can-anybody-give-me-a-working-example-of-generating-a-sha256-hash-in-c-with-cr)

[Using AES with Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306956/example-of-aes-using-crypto)